# Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer

Tags: spring-boot, docker, port

Some time ago I faced with such issue:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer:

    Property: server.port
    Value: $PORT
    Origin: "server.port" from property source "systemProperties"
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I tried to run my docker container in DigitalOcean.
I observed some similar topics here and I tried to apply advices. For instance I added **server.port=${PORT:8080}** to my application.properties but it didn't work for me.

Here's my docker run command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name nostalgia --env-file vars.txt --rm -it registry.digitalocean.com/alex-registry/nostalgia
```

And this is my vars.txt (only one variable at the moment):

```
PORT=8080
```

Also I should say that I tried another form of command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name nostalgia -e PORT=8080 --rm -it registry.digitalocean.com/alex-registry/nostalgia
```

But result is the same.
What should I do next to overcome this issue and successfully launch the container? Thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your server.port (Int) with docker env file (String). Just set your application property to server.port=8080 and remove the env file from your docker command.

If you need different port configurations you can do one of the following:

- work with multiple application.property files
- overwrite spring boot tomcat property directly in your docker command: -e SERVER_PORT=8080